# Increase 30 seconds lock time after incorrect attempts

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, security

If I try to unlock my Samsung Galaxy A3 (Android Version 5.0.2) with an incorrect password 5 times I have to wait 30 seconds before I can try again.
I want to increase this waiting time: how can I do that?

Comment: Try using some other third-party lockscreen app.. If that doesn't help, AFAIK only if your device is rooted you can use a Xposed app to do that..

Comment: @GokulNC do you have any third-party lockscreen app to suggest? My phone is not rooted and I don't plan to root it soon

Comment: Related: [Modify 30 second incorrect PIN delay](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43293)

Comment: I don't know if or which lock screen app supports such a setting; but while waiting for answers, be welcome to check my list of [Lock-Screen apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_lockscreen).

Comment: @Firelord I suppose this would require my phone to be rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by others in their previous comments, there is currently no application which would do that for you without requiring your phone to be rooted first.

***LockScreen Tweakbox*** (which is a module for the Xposed framework) can do this for you. However you need your phone to be rooted, plus, you will also need to install a custom recovery.

(Xposed Announcement for Android v5/6 + FAQ)
http://www.xda-developers.com/xposed-framework-for-android-lollipop-is-here/

(Download Xposed Framework for Android v5/6)
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811

(The actual module, which can only be installed an used once the Xposed Framework is installed and setup properly)
http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-lockscreen-tweakbox-various-t2843945

However, if you choose to root your phone and go through this solution, remember to **take a proper Nandroid backup** and a **backup of your current "boot.img"**. This is important and will save you a headache later on, in case something goes wrong during the process, which sometimes does happen, unfortunately.

Comment: The XDA thread for the module you linked, *Change allowed pattern attempts and timeout between them* is listed as *planned feature*, not the available feature. However, your answer doesn't mention this distinction. Would you consider proving your claim with screenshots?